# $R/I$ satisfies $S_2$ condition

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[x_1,...,x_{n},y_1,...,y_n]$ be a polynomial ring over a field $k$ and $I=\langle \{x_iy_j|$ for some $i,j \in\{1,...,n\}\}\rangle$ be ideal of $R$ and there are $r,s\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $x_ry_s\notin I$. Assume $R/I$ is a Buchsbaum ring. Suppose $(R/I)_p$ is Cohen-Macaulay for all $p\neq \langle x_1,...,x_{n},y_1,...,y_n\rangle$. Can we say that $R/I$ satisfies the Serre's $(S_2)$ condition?

See [here](http://rms.unibuc.ro/bulletin/pdf/53-2/Yasemi.pdf) (Theorem 1.3, (c) implies (d)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers the question for the case when $I$ were *the edge ideal of a non-complete bipartite graph*.

The only thing to prove is the following: $\operatorname{depth}R/I\ge\min(2,\dim R/I)$. It's obvious that $\dim R/I\ge 2$, so we have to prove $\operatorname{depth}R/I\ge2$. Since the graph $G$ is supposed non-complete the simplicial complex $\Delta_G$ is connected (see Lemma 1.2 from *Bipartite $S_2$ graphs are Cohen-Macaulay*). The result we use now says:

> Let $Δ$ be a simplicial complex on the vertex set $V$ and
>   $|V|\ge 2$. Then $\operatorname{depth}k[Δ] \ge 2$ if and only if the geometric realization of $Δ$ is connected.

For a proof see Hibi's paper [*Union and glueing of a family of Cohen-Macaulay partially ordered sets*](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118780771), Example A, page 8.

Comment: why $depth (R/I )_{(x_1,x_2,..x_n,y_1,y_2,..,y_n)}$ and $depth (R/I)$ are equal?

Comment: @Selva This holds for any graded $k$-algebra; see Proposition 1.5.15(e) in B&H (just set $M=R/I$).